# Do you compare your memories with others or others'?

Tags: possessives

You (plural) have different memories. Suppose you are all students in my class. Now I want to ask you to compare your memories by talking to students in another class and hearing about their memories. So should I say:

> Compare your memories with others?

or

> Compare your memories with others'?

The second makes more sense because you are not comparing your memories to people but to THEIR memories, but something about the sentence looks weird, so I thought to ask here.

Comment: If you are literally saying it, it makes no difference! If you are writing it - we would say "Compare your memories with other people's", so I guess the apostrophe is required.

Comment: The latter (with apostrophe) is safer. In both cases a piece is omitted yet assumed. With omitted parts included: (1) *Compare your memories with those of others*; (2) *Compare your memories with others' memories*.

Comment: Say either one. No one will notice the difference. Especially if you actually do say it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean. The difference is subtle, but there is a difference.

> Compare your memories with others.

Compare your memories with other memories. Obviously, the other memories must be other people's memories, but *others* here is referring to memories, not people. That is, *others* corresponds to *memories* in your sentence.

> Compare your memories with others'.

Compare your memories with those of other people. Here, *others'* matches *your* in your sentence.

I guess that in most cases, the sentence is directing you to the "those of other people" meaning, in which case an apostrophe is preferable.